# extracting song and artist from youtube music video

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am making a website, you can search or music video from youtube and play them on the website.
There's one problem. I cant extract the song and the artist from youtube properly.
I made this function:

```
$watch = $_GET['var'];
//id of the video
$code = $watch;
// Get video feed info (xml) from youtube, but only the title | http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
$video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$code."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
// xml to object | http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php
$video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
// Get the title string to a variable
$video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
// Output
echo "<br/>\n";
$new =  explode("-", $video_str);
```

`$watch` is the youtube video id.
the official music videos on youtube are like this: `eminem - without me`
the only way I could get the song and artist was like this. However for music videos the format is different. There is no " - " in the title, so I can't extract the information I need from youtube. I was wondering if there is any other way possible to do this.

Comment: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) a very similar question on StackOverflow, let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can always extract the artist by processing the raw xml on

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}
```

Comment: No more available

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether YT exposes [artist information](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/wNb6JLJteyU) via API. My best guess for a work around this is to have a different database of artists and then match the title or other metadata items for extracting the artist. 
You would need some mechanism for maintaining and updating the artist DB and relating videos to that.