# How to access licensed content included in a video using the YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

I want to access or collect the URL of the licensed content included in the video.

I have prepared a picture in case what I want is not conveyed properly

[image: red boxed area of this picture]

Here is part of the code I used:

```py
def youtube_videos(options):
  youtube = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPERKEY)

  search_response = youtube.videos().list(
    part = 'snippet, statistics, contentDetails, status',
    id = options,
    maxResults = 1
    ).execute()
  result = []
  for i in search_response['items']:
    result.append(i)
  print(result)
```

Can you tell me which part of the code needs to be modified, or provide a reference?

I'm also ready to learn how to work outside of the API.

We need your help, thank you as always.

Tried several request parameters including videos, search in YouTube API documentation but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/5b6bcceb3c174315869deb549eba8eac920e70d0/videos.php#L169-L244) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=musics&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get the musics contained in the video in `item["musics"]`.

[The YouTube video you shared `Ehoe35hTbuY`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ehoe35hTbuY) is a good video to test this feature of my API because it contains 10 musics. With this video id you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "Ehoe35hTbuY",
            "musics": [
                {
                    "song": {
                        "title": "Shape of You",
                        "videoId": "JGwWNGJdvx8"
                    },
                    "artists": [
                        {
                            "title": "Ed Sheeran",
                            "channelId": "UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "album": "Shape of You",
                    "writers": [
                        "Tameka \"Tiny\" Cottle",
                        "Kevin \"She'kspere\" Briggs",
                        "Johnny McDaid",
                        "Kandi Burruss",
                        "Ed Sheeran",
                        "Steve Mac"
                    ],
                    "licenses": "WMG (on behalf of East West Records UK Ltd); LatinAutor - Warner Chappell, ASCAP, AMRA, Spirit Music Publishing, LatinAutorPerf, BMI - Broadcast Music Inc., AMRA BR, LatinAutor - SonyATV, LatinAutor - UMPG, CMRRA, UMPI, Sony Music Publishing, BMG Rights Management (US), LLC, ARESA, SOLAR Music Rights Management, Abramus Digital, MINT_BMG, PEDL, UMPG Publishing, UNIAO BRASILEIRA DE EDITORAS DE MUSICA - UBEM, LatinAutor, Warner Chappell, and 17 Music Rights Societies"
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My endpoint also works for videos containing a single music such as [`DUT5rEU6pqM`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUT5rEU6pqM).

Comment: I just tried your answer and youtube id. There is nothing to return meaningful response. https://hizliresim.com/n4a7w05

Comment: [@BerkayOruç](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11475461/berkay-oru%c3%a7) [I just modified my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74652266/revisions), following [an API update](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/9a674c48bddc82d09c5ff11b02648241ba6a2f5a) that I proceeded to solving [your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74622099/how-to-access-licensed-content-included-in-a-video-using-the-youtube-api/74652266?noredirect=1#comment136512521_74652266).

Comment: Thank you for your really quick reply. But still there is no license. I think youtube api removed license content. (Yes, I know there is some response values, but they are not giving enough data)

Comment: [YT](https://imgur.com/a/g1fM648) changed since [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74622099). It does no more return the licenses. However, sometimes even for a given YT server it seems to randomly return previous data structure, as detailed in [this git issue comment](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/162#issuecomment-1799765450). The only potential solution would consist in a web-browser still having the previous view and being able to export the reproducible cURL request it has performed, as above git issue comment shows I tried many things but failed.

Comment: **UPDATE:** it seems that I found something wait a second and do not lose faith.

Comment: @BerkayOruç I finally achieved to force YouTube servers to return previous data structure, hence licenses, I updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if it does not solve the issue on your end. If so, please contact me on [Matrix](https://matrix.to/#/#youtube-operational-api:matrix.org) or [Discord](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/discord) to debug that together as it works fine on my end.

Comment: Save lots of people days. Thanks you a lot