# How to get artist name and title from youtube video with YouTube Data API?

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I saw similar questions, but they are already many years old, maybe something has changed?
I make a request to youtube to get video data.

```
(async () => {
   const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=${ID}&key=${API_KEY}&part=snippet,contentDetails`;
   const response = await axios.get(url);
   console.log(response.data.items[0]);
})();
```

I am getting the following object (part of it):

```
...
"snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2015-05-18T04:00:00Z",
      "channelId": "UCANLZYMidaCbLQFWXBC95Jg",
      "title": "Taylor Swift - Bad Blood ft. Kendrick Lamar",
      "description": "►Exclusive Merch: https://store.taylorswift.com\n \n►Follow Taylor Swift Online\nInstagram: http://www.instagram.com/taylorswift\nFacebook: http://www.facebook.com/taylorswift\nTumblr: http://taylorswift.tumblr.com\nTwitter: http://www.twitter.com/taylorswift13\nWebsite: http://www.taylorswift.com\n \n►Follow Taylor Nation Online\nInstagram: http://www.instagram.com/taylornation\nTumblr: http://taylornation.tumblr.com\nTwitter: http://www.twitter.com/taylornation13",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QcIy9NiNbmo/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
...
```

Title, description and data response for this part:
[image]

But below is exactly the part that I need:
[image]

Is there any way to get this data?

Comment: Duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74622099).

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is not available through the API.

You could either consider the [linked approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266/4092887) or use another way to extract the metadata of a given video.